# Event viewer export script

Tags: events, export

I am very new to scripting but I would like to script something useful for my company. I would like to be able to export a users event viewer logs in the click of a button without having to remote onto their PC and check event viewer, or access their share. I want it to be even that much faster so that it would automatically send me those files maybe in a zip folder perhaps? I am not too sure where to start with this though.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, you can start here, with PowerShell : http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/10/02/the-admin-s-first-steps-scan-multiple-event-logs.aspx

Comment: A python script would be very easy to write and has all the modules you need (zip a file easily).

Comment: okay thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good start would be this tutorial, for PowerShell :

[The Admin’s First Steps: Scan Multiple Event Logs (HSGB)](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/10/02/the-admin-s-first-steps-scan-multiple-event-logs.aspx)

there could be other ways, but PS provides some very convenient cmdlets to accomplish this.

Comment: Haha what do you mean by accepting the answer? Atleast I learned how to do it right:D? , Another question  for you though is how would I stop my Cmd window from closing. I did cmd  /c pause it says press any key to continue but then closes. I want it to go back to enter workstation ID. I'm assuming its a loop?

Comment: Accepting is just clicking the green check below the votes for my answer :) I cannot think too much about your next question right now, but I'll try to as soon as I can :)

Comment: Thanks! and can Get-EventLog put it in an exvt file?

Comment: Using other techniques, I found this https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Export-EventLog-18a87c2c and this https://4sysops.com/archives/managing-the-event-log-with-powershell-part-2-backup/

Comment: @Nick Levesque you should loop in powershell, not in cmd. You can also call 7-zip command line from PS to nicely zip whatever you retrieve.

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate it!